# R Matrix: Set Single Value of name referenced matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have matrices stored in variables i create out if strings through 
`assign( name, matrix(...) )`
Now i want to set a single value of this matrix providing its name, the row and col and the new value.
I would have imagined it like this:

```
get(name, envir = my.env)[x,y] <- value
```

or

```
assign(paste(name,"[",x,",",y,"]"),value, envir = my.env)
```

But both options do not work. Is there any nice way to adress this one particular field of the matrix? 
My current workaround is to first save the matrix to a variable, set its value and set the matrix back to its original variable.
It seems to me it is copying the matrix here as it leads to memory problems (the matrix is very big). I obviusoly would prefer other solutions

Comment: `mymatrix[row,col]<-newvalue` ? you may find that in any R tutorial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I would use a `list`, but you can work with an `environment` in pretty much the same way:

```
my.env <- new.env()
myname <- "mymat"
assign(myname, matrix(1:16, 4), envir = my.env)
my.env[[myname]][1, 1] <- 42
my.env[[myname]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   42    5    9   13
#[2,]    2    6   10   14
#[3,]    3    7   11   15
#[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't expect this would be so easy!

Answer (score 0):

Try `eval`:

```
my.env <- new.env()
name = 'd'
x = y = 1
assign(name, matrix(1:4, 2), envir=my.env)
eval(parse(text=paste(name, '[', x, ',', y, '] = ', value)), envir=my.env)
my.env[[name]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    3
# [2,]    2    4
```

Comment: [Fortune 106](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf): "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question."

Comment: @Roland Nice package.

Comment: Many of us have `if (interactive()) fortunes::fortune()` in our Rprofile.site file.

Comment: @Roland Really nice thing! Thanks for pointing towards this. :)